# Appending all xml files in a folder to single Dataframe using Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of xml files in a folder that I am trying to convert to csv and later append them to one Dataframe. The code below helps me to convert xml file to csv. The problem I have however is only the first file gets converted to csv and not the remaining files. Could anyone guide as to where am I going wrong in the below code:

```
for file in allFiles:
    print(file)
    def iter_docs(file):
        for docall in file:
            doc_dict = {}
            for doc in docall:
                tag = [elem.tag for elem in doc]
                txt = [elem.text for elem in doc]
                if len(tag) > 0:
                    doc_dict.update(dict(zip(tag, txt)))
                    else:
                        doc_dict[doc.tag] = doc.text
                    yield doc_dict
     etree = ET.parse(file_)
     df_0 = pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(etree.getroot())))
     df_0.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the DataFrame `df_0` appending all your data in the xml files and then save to csv file:

```
df_0 = pd.DataFrame()    # Create df to store all your data
for file in allFiles:        
    print(file)
    def iter_docs(file):
        for docall in file:
            doc_dict = {}
            for doc in docall:
                tag = [elem.tag for elem in doc]
                txt = [elem.text for elem in doc]
                if len(tag) > 0:
                    doc_dict.update(dict(zip(tag, txt)))
                    else:
                        doc_dict[doc.tag] = doc.text
                    yield doc_dict
     etree = ET.parse(file_)
     df_0 = df_0.append(pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(etree.getroot()))))    # Append data
df_0.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, this however just saves the last file to the Dataframe.. All the earlier files do not get saved..

Comment: Yeah, the declaration of the dataframe should be done before the for bucle, otherwise it is overwrite in every file. I edited the answer.